# advantages of using Borland C++ version 5

Tags: c++

What are advantages and disadvantages of using Borland C++ version 5

Comment: This didn't deserve the downvote...

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head...

Advantages:

- You can use [Object Windows Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Windows_Library), which many people think is very clean and easy to use
- Compatibility with other Borland code

Disadvantages:

- No longer supported - Old version of less popular compiler
- Newer, better supported free compilers exists
- Much smaller community compared to GCC or MVCC
- Less access to new technologies
- Doesn't support new C++ features